# Git multiple repositories in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control

I have a solution with five projects in it and want to add it under Git source control.

Since I want to limit access for some users to some projects, I have to set up a Git repository for each project and limit access on repository-level.

In Visual Studio however, Git repositories are created per-solution with sub-folders for each project it contains. Is there a possibility to map each project to a separate Git repository in Visual Studio? If not, how would I achieve my goal in any other way?

Comment: Took a little time, but now Visual Studio 2022 can handle multiple repositories.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

You could have a solution repository with the project repositories as submodules.